# Implementing one-to-one relation in SQL Server with two principle table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4.1, entity-relationship, relation

I have these three tables:

1:

[image]

2:

[image]

`Sell` and `Cheque` are in dependent upon `FinancialTransaction`.
As you see in the first picture, I have put `FinancialTransactionId` in dependent tables but I'm not sure that it is correct because as far as I know, One should put FK in the dependent table. In the other way if I put `ByeId` and `ChequeId` in the `FinancialTransaction`(Picture 2),one of them is always empty,so I don't know which method is right?
And in addition the principle tables could be more than two.

Comment: It's not clear, to me at least, what buy and cheque represent, could you clarify this? and do they contain other colums?

Comment: @ Sam Bauwens: Yes,they have other columns.the scenario is that money can come form both cheque or sell.

Comment: Cheque and sell will have same columns?

Comment: @Saksham : No they won't!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first approach is better and seems that it has no drawback.

But if you want to maintain the dependency in that order only, then a better approach could be to combine the cheque and sell table if they both have the same columns and add another boolean column **IsCheque** which will be set true or false depending on the payment mode.

**EDIT:**

Other approach could be to take a boolean column **IsPaymenyCheque** and another column as **PayModeID**. Based on the **IsPaymenyCheque**, refer to either of the table with **PayModeID**.

This would complex your queries as you will have to check for the Boolean value each time. Also you will have to remove the foreign key constraint.

Comment: Saksham :Thank you,that's very kind of you:)I prefer the first one .If it was one principle and one dependent table the second one would be better,because i could have cascade relationship,but in this case i think the first solution is better.

Answer (score 0):

The second solution is better in that it enforces the rule that a financial transaction can have at most 1 cheque and 1 sell.

Comment: As i said one of them is always empty!it can has a cheque or a Sell!

Comment: You CAN have a Foreign key on a nullable value, and @raha it's not that much of a problem to have one of the values being empty.

Comment: You can implement but it is not a good practice to have foreign keys as null. My bad.